# Using Regex (or simmilar) to change song name (or other tag) in itunes via script

Tags: python, string, applescript, itunes

So I have a scripting issue (and cannot find a specific app to do this in conjunction with itunes).

I can do something like this to any script in Python, Say I have as the song title:

Beat of my heart - original mix

and I want to change it to beat of my heart (original mix)

in Python I would:

```
string = 'Beat of my heart - original mix'
location = string.index(' - ')
fixed_string = string[,location] + '(' + string[location+3,] + ')'
```

simple right? 
But I want to batch this in itunes (on a mac) on the tracks I have labeled as such

Any suggestions?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Applescript, you can use `Text Item Delimiters`:

```
set ASTID to AppleScript's text item delimiters
tell application "iTunes"
    repeat with song in (selection of browser window 1)
        set the_name to name of song
        if the_name contains " - " then
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ("- ")
            set the_name to text items of the_name
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ("(")
            set the_name to (the_name as string) & ")"
            set name of song to the_name
        end if
    end repeat
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ASTID
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you! this seems to work, but can you help me modify your script? I changed one segment to every track of selection but that does not work. I don't want it running down the play list (although it could) but I prefer to get my selection (tracks i have highlighted in itunes). Is that possible?

Comment: I actually found the answer to my comment. see below, but since you wrote the original script I am choosing to accept your answer instead of my modified one.

Comment: My only problem with this Josh (not your fault) but its rather sllllooooowwwwww it took 300 tracks about 2-3 min... when you think about it ... should be very fast it is just text manipulation but... :(

Comment: @StudentOfScience sorry about the horribly slow response, I posted this and then went without a computer for a few hours. I edited my script so that it will only go through the selection. There are two reasons the program is so slow. Firstly, this is Applescript we're dealing with, so it'll be slow by nature, and secondly, I'm using `Text Item Delimiters`. If every song will be formatted like `ABC - original mix` then we can use string splicing to speed things up, but from the sound of it, the format is going to be more like `ABC - XYZ`, which means ASTID is still be the fasted way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set myTracks to get selection
    repeat with aTrack in myTracks
        set trackName to aTrack's name
        set newTrackName to do shell script "sed 's/ - \\(.*\\)/ (\\1)/' <<< " & quoted form of trackName
        if newTrackName ≠ trackName then set aTrack's name to newTrackName
    end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you have an answer, however I wanted to point out that you can parse a string in applescript in virtually the same manner as your python code. Just use "offset" to find the text position. Simple right?

```
set theString to "Beat of my heart - original mix"
set theLocation to offset of " - " in theString
set fixed_string to text 1 thru theLocation of theString & "(" & text (theLocation + 3) thru end of theString & ")"
```

NOTE: if the offset text is not found then theLocation will be 0 so you can add an if statement if needed before the last line.

Answer (score 0):

```
set ASTID to AppleScript's text item delimiters
tell application "iTunes"
    set sel to selection
    if sel is not {} then
        repeat with aTrack in sel
            set the_name to name of aTrack
            if the_name contains " - " then
                set AppleScript's text item delimiters to (" - ")
                set the_name to text items of the_name
                set AppleScript's text item delimiters to (" (")
                set the_name to (the_name as string) & ")"
                set name of aTrack to the_name
            end if
        end repeat
    end if
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ASTID
end tell
```

Comment: this code above is the same as @Josh code except that I modified it to get a selection instead of running through an entire playlist. Thx Josh